# Meaning of "this is a routine chapter"

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives

Does "this is a routine chapter" mean that there is no creativity in this chapter?

Context:

> This is a routine chapter. There is almost nothing creative here. I just
>   generalize theorems about funcoids to the maximum extent for  (defined below) preserving the proof idea. The main idea behind
>   this chapter is to find weakest theorem conditions enough for the same
>   theorem statement as for above theorems for funcoids.
>
> For these who know pointfree topology: Pointfree topology notions of frames
>   and locales is a non-trivial generalization of topological spaces. Pointfree
>   funcoids are different: I just replace the set of filters on a set with an
>   arbitrary poset, this readily gives the definition of , no need of creativity here.

Comment: Generally speaking a "routine" is a set of normal procedures, often performed mechanically. So, yes, there is no creativity in these sort of chapters; but "routine" is also a set piece of entertainment, especially in a nightclub or theater. Thus only context can clarify whether or not in "routine" there is creativity.

Comment: Can you give more context and show the results of your research, please?

Comment: @Cameron: I've added the context

Comment: "Routine" can also mean "ordinary, plain, unexceptional", as in, "It was just another routine day at the office." The writer might mean that the chapter is dull or mechanical in that sense. I presume he thinks the chapter is of value or why did he include it, but he is warning the reader that this is going to be a dull slog and he just has to get through it.

Comment: @Jay: "The writer" is me

Comment: You should ask for some help on [Writers Stack Exchange.](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions) (With all respect, you have greater issues than the word choice of *routine.*)

Answer (score 1):

In general, a chapter being routine need not mean there is no creativity in the chapter; there always are choices to be made about organization, about techniques, about examples.

Note, as JLG suggests, you should ask for some help on [Writers Stack Exchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com), for advice about problems with the passage.  There is no reason for a thesis, technical report, or scientific paper to include, and there is good reason to exclude, sentences or phrases like “There is almost nothing creative here”,  “I just generalize”,  “For these who know pointfree topology”,  “I just replace”, “routine”, or “no need of creativity here”.  Instead, the introduction to the chapter might talk about setting up patterns for efficient proof of theorems and about required due diligence in proving generalizations or specializations of theorems, and might mention any subsections of the chapter that contain different or interesting results or proofs.